# append all forms checkbox data with single submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I've multiple forms each having multiple checkboxes. For all the forms there is a single submit provided at some where down in the page so that when clicked it will previews all the checkboxed info

```
<form name="a1" action="start.php" method="post"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="x1">x1 
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="x2">x2
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="x3">x3
</form>

<form name="a2" action="start.php" method="post"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="y1">y1 
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="y2">y2
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="y3">y3
</form>

<form name="a3" action="start.php" method="post"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="z1">z1 
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="z2">z2
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="z3">z3
</form>

<div> <input type="submit" value="preview" onclick="addForm()"> </div>
```

where in `validateform` is

```
<script type="text/javascript">function addForm(){
document.forms["a1"].submit();
document.forms["a2"].submit();
document.forms["a3"].submit();
}
```

and `start.php` is

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check."<br/>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Problem is am not able to append all forms the data by the function `addForm()`
Please help me understand how all the check boxes info can be shown which taken from all forms with PHP

Comment: Why not just use ONE form with all the elements in it instead of three?

Comment: @Pointy in flash each form is shown with some animation, so its obvious to have multiple forms in my view

Comment: I'm not a Flash expert by any means, but this doesn't sound like a PHP question to me. More of a "How do I get all of these forms to submit at once in Flash?"

Comment: @Codeacula I'll embed div-forms into a flash showup, and flash has nothing to do other than showing it

Answer (score 2):

When you call the submit function on the first form "a1", you automatically send the data to start.php, and the other two forms wont be submitted. Best solution: **ajax**

XMLHTTPRequest allows you to post forms and get a reply without leaving the page and you can combine the results from all three form submits and display them together

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to submit more than one form at once in this manner. If you wanted to take this approach, you would need to use AJAX, as this is the only way to have the browser maintain more than one active request.

Looking at the code though, I can't see any reason that you would need more than one form. You should be able to simply do this:

```
<form name="a1" action="start.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="x1">x1 
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="x2">x2
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="x3">x3
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="y1">y1 
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="y2">y2
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="y3">y3
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="z1">z1 
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="z2">z2
  <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="check_list[]" value="z3">z3
  <div><input type="submit" value="preview"></div>
</form>
```

...for which you don't even need any Javascript.

Comment: in flash each form is shown with some animation, so its obvious to have multiple forms in my view

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish and what the animation does.

Comment: Presumably you could group the checkboxes in divs and then show the animations based on these groupings?

Answer (score 1):

If you're the author of HTML code in question, I'd suggest you refactor your code and create only one form that envelops all the checkboxed *and* the submit button. If it's styling that troubles you, you can simply place input elements in appropriate `<fieldset>` elements.

Otherwise, if you're stuck with HTML code that you did not write, I'd suggest that you do the following (although it's really not a pretty solution):

Edit the `addForm()` function to create a fourth `<form>` element somewhere in the document, and set its style to `display: none;`. Then append or clone all the checkboxes from previous forms to this new form, and submit it. That should give you a collection of checkboxes which you can handle on PHP side like you would if the initial HTML code was written properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data to go to start.php, you should simply use a single form.

Side note: You shouldn't have the id attribute of the inputs all set to "add". id should be unique.

Comment: in flash each form is shown with some animation, so its obvious to have multiple forms in my view

Answer (score 0):

If you must have multiple form for this, like you state in a comment then you need more extensive javascript.

One form submit = one http request, 3 won't work, but what you can do is bind all those form so when one is submitted you can collect the data of ALL inputs in ALL forms and serialize the lot and then send that as a GET request. remember to disable the default behaviour so the form doesn't submit as such.

Or if you must have a POST request, create a temporary form and create input with the correct values inside then submit that form.

Comment: can i dynamically take all the data into an array so that to some extent this submit issue gets fixed!

Answer (score 0):

For submitting multiple form you have two solutions:

1) Using Ajax request
2) Append all the information in a final form and submit that, for doing so you can simply use jQuery or javascript.